# How to get total size of object during runtime?

Tags: c++, memory

I know that you can use the sizeof() method. However, this method works in a static fashion. Is there anything that will basically return the total size (memory footprint) of an instance of an object during runtime? Suppose that this object contains maps and other complex data structures as well. I want to be able to invoke code such as:

```
get_total_size(myObject) <-- would return 1 MB or however large it actually is in memory
```

Comment: I’d love to be corrected but I don’t think that’s possible in C++ since you’re need reflection to traverse the object graph.

Comment: There is no other way than calculating it yourself, because only you as a developer know whether to calculate referenced objects towards footprint or not.

Comment: meaning-matters: I want to know this because I am trying to figure out why the application's memory footprint is increasing dramatically in some cases. I'm trying to isolate the object(s) that are causing this problem.

Comment: @Andrew use a debugger. It should show that kind of info.

Comment: @Andrew: What about a `shared_ptr<BigObject>` ? Could that be 100.25 bytes? It's just not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing. Generally it would be hard, since even if an object contains something, it may share data with other objects.

Comment: That's fine if that's the case. I just want to know if a certain object is the cause of the issue I am running into.

Comment: Try empirical way: measure the total footprint of your program, create big number of your objects and you will know.